# Handle Logout in Federated authentication in windows azure

Tags: c#, facebook, azure

I am using federated authentication in windows azure with facebook as identity provider
i followed following link and some other helps to get me through

http://debugmode.net/2011/11/13/step-by-step-guide-on-federated-authentication-in-windows-azure-web-role-using-windows-azure-app-fabric-access-control-service/

now i am not sure how to handle logout in the same. can anybody help out there!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 fam.SignOut(true); 
 // Write your code to Redirect to home page after Log Out
```

Find more details on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/18/how-to-perform-clean-logout-from-your-application-which-use-azure-acs-amp-identity-providers.aspx

All the best.